# Transform 2D embeddings into 3D embeddings

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I want to fuse node embeddings from a GNN shaped {[N, 128], where N can vary, with hidden state from an LSTM shaped [2, 32, 128]. To do so, I wanted to add both feature tensors, but they need to be the same shape.
I have something like:

```
N = 75
t = torch.rand(N, 128)
t.unsqueeze_(0)
t = t.expand(2,N, 128)
```

I do not seem to figure out how to make dimension 1 equal to 32. I am looking for some combination of transforms and learnable layers that can help me make this shape conversion. Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: So you want to convert a tensor from [75,128] shape to [2,75,128] in your example to create a 3D tensor from a 2D?

Comment: I would like to convert [75, 128] into [2, 32, 128]. This is meant to be a fusing step in between learnable layers so additional layers can be used. For example, I could flatten it all and pass it through a linear layer, but I would like to concatenate or add the first embedding (shaped [75, 128]) to the second embedding (shaped [2, 32, 128]).

Comment: 75x128 does not equal 2x32x128. The number of elements does not add up in this conversion, so you need to explain how you'd like to condense or pool the elements from the variable-sized node embeddings into a fixed size. There are arbitrarily many ways you could do this but not necessarily that preserve the information in the embeddings that you care about

Comment: Concretely, how can you make a learnable conversion from `N` values to 32 values when `N` is changeable?

Comment: I am currently trying to use AdaptiveAveragePooling